# Response.ok vs http response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, spring-restcontroller

In the spring Rest Controller , What is the difference between ResponseEntity.ok vs sending the response directly. Anyway i'm getting 200 if the response is success in both the scenario.

For Ex: - ResponseEntity.ok(list) or send just send the list

Answer (score 0):

With ResponseEntity you can have more fine-grained control of the response object, for example you can set additional headers or custom return code.

If you just respond with either list or ResponseEntity.ok(list), there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using `ResponseEntity` as return type is to send different status codes on based on available data

For example of you have only return type of `List<String>`, then the HTTP response status code will always be 200 and you will not be able to send any other status code

```
public List<String> getResponse() {

}
```

But if you have `ResponseEntity<List<String>>` as return type you can send the required status code with appropriate data

```
 public List<String> getResponse() {
  ResponseEntity.status(HttStatus.ACCEPTED).body(list)
 ResponseEntity.status(HttStatus.NOT_FOUND).build()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When an endpoint returns successfully, Spring provides an HTTP 200 (OK) response. If the endpoint throws an exception, Spring looks for an exception handler that tells which HTTP status to use.Which means using as long as your response is sent successfully the status is always 200.But if you want to customize the response ResponseEntity is more flexible.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity